# Django/Python "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'contact'. Check that '...apps.contact.apps.ContactConfig.name' is correct"

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, configuration, modulenotfounderror

Hopefully you all can give me a hand with this...

my work flow:

```
|.vscode:
|capstone_project_website:
|   -_pycache_:
|   -apps:
|       -_pycache_
|       -accounts:
|       -contact:    # app that is throwing errors
|           -_pycache_:
|          -migrations:
|          -_init_.py
|          -admin.py
|          -apps.py
|          -forms.py
|          -models.py
|          -test.py
|          -urls.py
|          -views.py 
|       -public:
|       -_init_.py
|   -templates: # all my .html 
|   -_init_.py
|   -asgi.py
|   -settings.py
|   -urls.py
|   -views.py
|   -wsgi.py
|requirements:
|scripts:
|static:
|.gitignore
|.python-version
|db-sqlite3
|docker-compose.yml
|Dockerfile
|Makefile #command I am running
|manage.py
|setup.cfg
```

my Installed apps in `capstone_project_website/settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
"django.contrib.admin",
"django.contrib.auth",
"django.contrib.contenttypes",
"django.contrib.sessions",
"django.contrib.messages",
"django.contrib.staticfiles",
"capstone_project_website.apps.accounts",
"capstone_project_website.apps.contact", ]
```

my `capstone_project_website/apps/contact/apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ContactConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "contact"
```

the command I am running is in my `Makefile`:

```
compose-start:
    docker-compose up --remove-orphans $(options)
```

When I run `make compose-start` I get this message from my Terminal:

```
make compose-start
docker-compose up --remove-orphans
Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

Starting django-website_postgres_1 ... done
Starting django-website_db_migrate_1 ... done
Starting django-website_website_1    ... done

Attaching to django-website_postgres_1, django-website_db_migrate_1, django-website_website_1
db_migrate_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
db_migrate_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 244, in create
db_migrate_1  |     app_module = import_module(app_name)
db_migrate_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
db_migrate_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
db_migrate_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
db_migrate_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
db_migrate_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
db_migrate_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'contact'
db_migrate_1  |
db_migrate_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
db_migrate_1  |
db_migrate_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
db_migrate_1  |   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
db_migrate_1  |     main()
db_migrate_1  |   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
db_migrate_1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
db_migrate_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
db_migrate_1  |     utility.execute()
db_migrate_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
db_migrate_1  |     django.setup()
db_migrate_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
db_migrate_1  |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
db_migrate_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
db_migrate_1  |     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
db_migrate_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 250, in create
db_migrate_1  |     app_config_class.__qualname__,
db_migrate_1  | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'contact'. Check that 'capstone_project_website.apps.contact.apps.ContactConfig.name' is correct.
postgres_1    |
postgres_1    | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1    |
postgres_1    | 2021-05-02 14:17:44.105 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1    | 2021-05-02 14:17:44.106 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1    | 2021-05-02 14:17:44.106 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1    | 2021-05-02 14:17:44.113 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1    | 2021-05-02 14:17:44.121 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-05-02 14:17:17 UTC
django-website_db_migrate_1 exited with code 1
postgres_1    | 2021-05-02 14:17:44.129 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
website_1     | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping django-website_website_1    ... done
Stopping django-website_postgres_1   ... done
```

I know I put a lot of my work flow in, but I am wondering if I am setting it up incorrectly. I have run into this problem before when trying to `makemigrations` on my accounts app. the answer to that one seemed to work.
the answer was to change the `name` in `capstone_project_website/apps/accounts/apps.py` to

```
class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "capstone_project_website.apps.accounts"
```

and in installed apps you can see the path is:

```
"capstone_project_website.apps.accounts",
```

I have tried changing the name of... `capstone_project_website/apps/contact/apps.py`

```
class ContactConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "contact"
```

... to `name='capstone_project_website.apps.contact'`
...and my installed app name to:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "capstone_project_website.apps.ContactConfig", ]
```

Point being I am unsure what is going on, if it is a directory issue, a name issue or if there is some step I am missing before I `make compose-start`. If you could help me with this, and explain what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it!
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried making migrations and migrating????

Comment: Yes, I still get some form of ImportError.  `raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Module 'capstone_project_website.apps' does not contain a 'ContactConfig' class.
ERROR: 1
make: *** [compose-manage-py] Error 1`

Answer (score 17):

try changing this:

> class ContactConfig(AppConfig):
> name = "contact"

to this:

> class ContactConfig(AppConfig):
> name = "apps.contact"

Comment: What does this do? I had a similar problem, and adding 'apps.' in the name seems to work when I try to run a test in PyCharm, but it will fail other builds/composes with an error of 

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'app.splitter'. Check that 'splitter.apps.SplitterConfig.name' is correct.`
( splitter is the name of the app )

Answer (score 2):

Check your django version. If you update your django version to **3.2**, try to switch with the earliest one.

> django==3.1.8

Comment: when I did `pip freeze` it says I'm using:  `Django==3.2`

Comment: Please switch to `django==3.1.8` and let me know the error. They have changes the app_config. Probably for this reason, you are getting error.

Comment: just ran it and it is still saying it can't find my app. `ImportError: Module 'capstone_project_website.apps' does not contain a 'ContactConfig' class.`

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to `python` `version`, so I was having similar issue with Python version `3.7.x`. But when I switched to `3.9.x`, it got resolved.

Here is what I was trying to do:

```
(base) Imrans-MacBook-Pro:django-vue imran$ source ./venv/bin/activate
(venv) (base) Imrans-MacBook-Pro:django-vue imran$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/imran/Workspace/django-vue/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
```

Then I ssh into the docker setup with `3.9` and here are the results:

```
(venv) (base) Imrans-MacBook-Pro:django-vue imran$ docker-compose exec backend sh
# python --version
Python 3.9.15
# python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'core':
  core/migrations/0003_product.py
    - Create model Product
```